# Change content of the same column and write to the same file

Tags: python

I wanted to change the content of column 2(a single character) of every line in a file into alphabet "k", here is my code:

```
f = open('test.txt')
f_str = f.readlines()
f.close()

for line in f_str:
    s = list(line)
    s[1] = "k"
    line = ''.join(s)
    print line   

f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(f_str)      
f.close()
```

I managed to change the content in the for loop(the print result shows that), but I failed to write the changed result to the file. Please, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You write out the exact same text that you read in: `f.writelines(f_str)`. You never updated `f_str`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the reply, I thought `f_str` was updated in the for loop, because `line` is an element of `f_str`, and `line`'s value was changed. I am at a loss here...

Comment: When you iterate over `f_str` and modify `line` you are not editing it in place. The values in `f_str` don't get changed.

Comment: @Tim thank you again for your prompt reply, I am not sure what you meanty by "not editing it in place", could you please explain it in more detail? thank you so much :)

Comment: When you modify the value of `line` in the loop a new variable is created under the hood. The values in `f_str` aren't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't update `f_str`, so you end up writing out the exact same lines that you read in. Instead of printing the modified lines, add them to a new list.

```
new_lines = []
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = list(line)
        new_line[1] = "k"
        new_lines.append(''.join(new_line))

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(new_lines)
```

Comment: It is worth adding that `s = list(line)` creates a new object - a new list. Same with `line = ''.join(s)` - a new string is created, rather than modifying "old" line object. "Old" line object stays intact.

Comment: @Tim thank you for the answer, @dmitri it seems a little weird to me that `line` should be created as a new string, anyway, I am pretty much a newbie though, need to work at on this...